# control external peripherals over serial from Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: serial, pi-3

*Raspberry Pi 3* GPIO pins 8 and 10 are `UART Tx` and `UART Rx` respectively. Is it possible to use those pins to control external peripherals(for example network device which is managed over serial port) over RS-232 port? If not, then is it possible to use unused GPIO pins for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pins to connect to a serial peripheral provided you ensure that it is 3.3V or employ level converters. You will find many posts on this site with suggestions.

You should NOT connect to a serial port with a DB9 connection. The best way to do this is with one of the serial to RS-232 converters.

NOTE that the Pi3 has some issues with serial. See [How-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697) for a discussion and a solution.

Comment: Thanks! I am aware of level converters. However, what do you mean by "serial to RS-232 converters"? Is this a same as TTL <-> RS-232 converter using MAX232 chip?

Comment: @Martin There are many and this chip is commonly used. These all safely interface with what are (incorrectly) called RS-232 and convert to lower unipolar voltages. You need to ensure that any such module will interface to 3.3V not just TTL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. These pins are a serial port. HOWEVER, you have a hurdle or two first. Their polarity is absolutely definitely unequivocally reversed, so when the pins output a logic high, it is actually a logic low which is presented and vice-versa. Further, by comparison to the 12V signals which might be encountered on other types of COM port, these are TTL signals at 5V.

To convert them to a traditional COM port, you'll need an RS232-TTL convertificator (e.g. the tried and tested MAX232 http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/max232.pdf). As can be seen from teh data sheet, not only does this device convert the 5V logic levels from the Raspberry Pi to the higher voltages levels specified by an RS-232 port, but it also inverts the logic levels for you, such that logic high = logic high.

These can be bought as ready-made modules, even with a 9-pin serial connector already attached.

By default, I think the pins make the RPi shell available to a serial terminal using these pins, so you need disable that feature int eh kernel (use the raspi-config program).

The device you need to read/write was /dev/ttyAMA0.

Find everything you need to know about making it work from Python here: http://pyserial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyserial.html

Comment: I don't know what makes you think "polarity is reversed" and they are most definitely NOT "5V TTL signals". Incidentally, if you do manage to find a PC with a serial port, it is unlikely to have 12V signals.

Comment: The device USED to be `/dev/ttyAMA0`, and this still works on Pi2 and earlier. You should use `/dev/serial0` on recent Raspbian.